# Filter queryset objects based on who user follows (Django)

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out a feature in a web app whereby a logged-in user can filter objects within a specific set of coordinates that have been "listed" by other users who the logged-in user follows. (I'm using Google Maps API)

I have gotten it to the point where the objects within the coordinates show up but I can't figure out the next step whereby these objects are filtered again so only objects "listed" by users whom the logged-in user follows show up.

Here is what I do have:
Views

```
def get_friends(request):
    template_name = 'testingland/electra.html'
    neLat = request.GET.get('neLat', None)
    neLng = request.GET.get('neLng', None)
    swLat = request.GET.get('swLat', None)
    swLng = request.GET.get('swLng', None)
    ne = (neLat, neLng)
    sw = (swLat, swLng)

    xmin = float(sw[1])
    ymin = float(sw[0])
    xmax = float(ne[1])
    ymax = float(ne[0])
    bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

    geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(geolocation__coveredby=geom)
    user = request.user
    print(user)

    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address, cafe.geolocation.y, cafe.geolocation.x]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```

Models:

```
class mapCafes(models.Model): 
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cafe_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cafe_long = models.FloatField()
    cafe_lat = models.FloatField()
    geolocation = models.PointField(geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
    venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image_embed = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'a_cafes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cafe_name

class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name

class UserVenue(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(mapCafes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user_list = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user_list','venue']

class UserConnections(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="following", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Do you add instances of `UserConnections` where `follower` is the person who follows someone and `followed` is the target? So If I follow you its follower=Felix, followed=deadant88

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kinda sloppy but something like this should work if I've understood your models correct.

```py
friends = UserConnections.objects.filter(
    follower=request.user
).values_list('followed__pk', flat=True)

mapCafes.objects.filter(
    geolocation__coveredby=geom,
    uservenue__user_list__user__pk__in=friends
).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I get this error: 
``django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: authusergroups, authuseruserpermissions, date_joined, djangoadminlog, email, first_name, followers, following, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, replycomments, user_permissions, userlist, username, venuecomments, venuelist``

Comment: PS. also added `.distinct()` to last query now.

Comment: Hey thanks, so I get this error ``AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cafe_name'`` but I think it's to do with the ``return`` data: I updated ``qs`` to ``friends``

Comment: Yes it works, I had to just update the JSON Response as well. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would like to filter your queryset of `MapCafe`s to ones that are on a user list that belongs to a user followed by `request.user`.

```
MapCafes.objects.filter(
    uservenue__user_list__user__follower=request.user
)
```

Notice also that the `UserVenue` model is a many to many connection between `MapCafes` and `UserList`s. We can specifiy this on the `UserList` class.

```
class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venues = models.ManyToManyField(MapCafes, through='UserVenue')
```

This gives you an explicit connection between the venues and the user lists and you can do

```
MapCafes.objects.filter(
    userlist__user__follower=request.user
)
```

And in other pars of your application, if you have a `UserList` instance, you can get the `MapCafes` by doing `userlist.venues.all()`.

Comment: Thank you but I got the following error  (using your first suggestion) 
``django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: follower``
Not sure how to post fuller traceback

Comment: Sorry, I left out the full name of the model. Hopefully that edit fixes it.

Comment: All good! Sorry, another error now :( ``ValueError: Cannot query "bob": Must be "UserList" instance.``

Comment: Sorry, made another edit. Not easy when you can't test the code yourself.

Comment: All good! I appreciate the help! Sadly another error ``Related Field got invalid lookup: userconnection``

Comment: I don't know if that latest edit is going to work or not, but you can try. :-)